# how to draw a blur line with finger touches on iPhone?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, blur

How do I draw a blur line with a finger slide/touch motion on the iPhone? I have the following code but it is not worked. It do it wit core-graphics.some sample code?
Thanks!!

```
CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth);

CGContextSaveGState(context);
{

    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(-2.0f, 2.0f), 7.0f, BLACK.CGColor);

    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.lineColor.CGColor);
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
CGContextRestoreGState(context);

CGPathRelease(path);
```

Comment: What does it do and what do you want it to do differently?

Comment: What do you mean by "**blur** line"?

Comment: just want to the drawing line looks like an image fuzzy using core image.I know android can do it easy.But to iOS,I am don't know

Comment: did you get solution?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/18840/how-to-make-a-simple-drawing-app-with-uikit) is the code for simple drawing method. Hope this will help you to implement your code.

Comment: NONONO.That's just can draw simple line.I want blur it when drawing shapes.Thank you all the same.